# Clarification about a metric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

This is rather an easy question but I am a bit confused about the following metric

$\rho(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})
 := \sup_{A\in \mathcal{G}} \inf_{B\in \mathcal{H}} \mu(A \triangle B) + \sup_{B\in \mathcal{H}} \inf_{A\in \mathcal{G}} \mu(A \triangle B)$

where $A\Delta B$ is symmetric difference and $\mu$ is a measure for some underlying probability space. Now I want to understand what this implies for finite sets if we replace $\mu$ with cardinality of sets. Consider

$\mathcal{G}=\{\left\{1,2,3,4 \right\}\}, \mathcal{H}=\{\{ 2\},\{1,3,4\}\}$

I found distance between these two sets as $4$ but I am not sure. Any confirmation and/or clarification is greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: That’s correct: the first term is $1=\min\{1,3\}$, and the second is $3=\max\{1,3\}$.

Comment: You’re welcome!